# SQLAlchemy - When does accessing a Backref/relationship cause a query to the DB, and when does it not?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm having trouble understanding when SQLAlchemy will make a query to the database and when it will not when a backref or relationship is accessed.

**In what situations does accessing a reltionship or backref cause a query to the DB?**

From the [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#using-loader-strategies-lazy-loading-eager-loading):

> The scalar or collection attribute associated with a relationship() contains a trigger which fires the first time the attribute is accessed. This trigger, in all but one case, issues a SQL call at the point of access in order to load the related object or objects... The one case where SQL is not emitted is for a simple many-to-one relationship, when the related object can be identified by its primary key alone and that object is already present in the current Session.

Clearly, this call to `.children` will result in a SQL:

```
parent = session.query(Parent).filter_by(id=1).one()
parent.children
```

As well this call to `.parent`:

```
child = session.query(Child).filter_by(id=1).one()
child.parent
```

I'm operating under the assumption that the above documention snippit implies that neither the call to `.parent` or to `.children` in the following will cause a query. Is this correct?

```
parents = []
children = []
for parent, child in db.session.query(Parent, Child).join(Child):
    parents.append(parent)
    children.append(child)

parents[0].children
children[0].parent
```

Comment: `parents[0].children` will incur a query, `children[0].parent` will not.

Comment: @univerio do you happen to know if there is anyway for me to demonstrate that in the shell?

Comment: You can get SQLAlchemy to print the queries issued by setting `echo=True` in `create_engine`.